# MySQL update one-to-many from one table to another

Tags: mysql, inner-join, updates

I have table1 with accountNum and emailAddr (one entry per account number) and table2 with the same two fields but can have multiples (several records with same account number).  I want to update table2 email addresses from table1.  I tried this but it just hung and didn't do anything:

```
update table2 
inner join table1 on t1acct = t2acct 
set t2email = t1email 
where t2status = "A";
```

Please assist.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that the column names are correct that query should work (see this fiddle for a demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42230/1) Is the query timing out or does it complete but does just not do anything?

Comment: The query just runs for a while ... I let it go 5 min the aborted it ... then checked and no emails were set.  There are 3750 records in table1 and 5900 records in table2

Comment: Could be a locking issue perhaps, the query should be valid.

Comment: Also it locks up MySQL so no other queries can run while the above query is running.  I've never seen that happen.

Comment: Please consider **qualifying** the column references with the table name or a table alias. We're really just guessing which table the columns `t1acct`, `t2acct`, `t2email`, `t1email` and `t2status` are referencing. (We don't have a schema definition; we can guess, but our guesses will probably be wrong.) And having appropriate indexes available should help with performance. Again, we're left guessing whether there's an index with leading column of `t2acct`, for example. "Use the EXPLAIN, Luke."

Comment: jpw was right ... sql was good ... I created a program to do the same and it took 30 minutes ... I just never seen a query hang MySQL like that.